# Weird texture problem (Small vertex)

Tags: texturing

I've ran into a problem where when I apply a texture, the vertex on the Texture is very small and can't be scaled (It's really weird trying to describe this so here's some images).

[image: How it looks like, notice the small orange on the texture, can't be scaled up.]

GIF: https://i.imgur.com/Lp3eFXw.gifv

Is there anything I can do to make it look normal, it was normal yesterday and today it seems to be doing this on this texture and the gloves, it's really weird and confusing.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the blend file? It might be something with the active UVmap... hace you tried to UV unwraping again?

Comment: You probably *welded* the uv island- try to unwrap the model again.

Comment: How would I go about unwrapping it? When attempting to, it puts it into triangle (As does removing the UV Map) . Is there no way to reset it back to normal? I've managed to fix the eyes by importing it from the default unedited model and it worked normally, here's the files as the gloves are still broken with this problem: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n3DJyJ_8mQA1ZCOXrNAZx4mNXRxBVdP6